# Least square surface fitting from first principles

Tags: matlab, optimization, surface

I want to make this "by hand" rather than using a surface fitting tool, because depending on the data I have, the surface fitting may vary. So, I first read the data in an excel sheet, then initialize some coefficients, calculate a 3D surface (f(x,y)) and then calculate the total least squares sum, which I'd like to minimise. Every time I run the script it tells me that I'm at the local minimum, even when I change the initial values. Changing the tolerance doesn't affect the result either.

This is the code:

```
% flow function in a separate .m file (approximation, it’s a negative paraboloid, maybe if required, this function may vary):

function Q = flow(P1,P2,a,b,c,d,e,f)
Q1 = a-b.*P1-c.*P1.^2;
Q2 = d-e.*P2-f.*P2.^2;
Q = Q1 + Q2;

% Variable read, I use a xlsread instead
p1a = [-5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5];
p2a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
qa = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

p1b = [-6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6, -6];
p2b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
qb = [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3];

% Variable initialization
coef = [50, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1];

% Function calculation
q1a = flow(p1a,p2a,coef(1),coef(2),coef(3),coef(4),coef(5),coef(6)); 
q1b = flow(p1b,p2b,coef(1),coef(2),coef(3),coef(4),coef(5),coef(6));

% Least squares
LQa = (qa-q1a).^2;
LQb = (qb-q1b).^2;
Sa = sum(LQa);
Sb = sum(LQb);
St = Sa+Sb;

% Optimization (minimize the least squares sum)
func = @(coef)(St);
init = coef;
opt = optimoptions('fminunc', 'Algorithm', 'quasi-newton', 'Display', 'iter','TolX', 1e-35, 'TolFun', 1e-30);
[coefmin, Stmin] = fminunc(func, init, opt);
```

If you run this, you should get a result of `15546` for `Stmin`, but if you change the coefficients, you'll get another result, and it will also be considered as a local minimum.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you say you're hitting a different local minimum when you change the initial values? That sounds pretty normal... one workaround is to seed it with a few different vectors of initial values and then choose the one that performs best (a multi-start strategy)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know that. The problem is that the first iteration shows me the minimum, and that's not ok. And I also know with 6 degrees of freedom I can have an infinite set of results (local minimums), and another infinite set of results for global minimums. I don't care which values are found for each coefficient (I have no restrictions), I just need a global optimum (one) that will allow me (and anyone who wants to use this code) to better fit my experimental points with a polynomial 2nd degree expression.

Comment: OK I see now, that was not clear from your question. The problem is how you have defined `func`. I've posted an answer showing how it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `func` is just a constant. It simply returns a *pre-calculated* value, `St`, which is constant no matter what input you pass to `func`. Try calling `func` with various different inputs to test this.

Your objective function needs to contain all the calculations that got you to `St`. So I suggest you replace your `func` with a function saved in an m-file looking something like this:

```
function St = objectiveFunction(coef, p1a, p2a, p1b, p2b, qa, qb, q1a, q1b)

    % Function calculation
    q1a = flow(p1a,p2a,coef(1),coef(2),coef(3),coef(4),coef(5),coef(6)); 
    q1b = flow(p1b,p2b,coef(1),coef(2),coef(3),coef(4),coef(5),coef(6));

    % Least squares
    LQa = (qa-q1a).^2;
    LQb = (qb-q1b).^2;
    Sa = sum(LQa);
    Sb = sum(LQb);
    St = Sa+Sb;

end
```

And then in your script call `objectiveFunction` using an anonymous function like this:

```
[coefmin, Stmin] = fminunc(@(coef)(objectiveFunction(coef, p1a, p2a, p1b, p2b, qa, qb, q1a, q1b)), init, opt);
```

The idea is to create an anonymous function that only takes a single parameter, `coef`, which is the variable that `fminunc` will peturb and pass back to your objective function. The other parameters that your `objectiveFunction` needs (i.e. `p1a, p2a, p1b,...`) are now considered to be pre-calculated by your anonymous function and thus by `fminunc`.

The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan. I hope this code could bring some ideas to the rest of the community. Regards.